# Send PDF file path to client to download after covnersion in WeasyPrint

Tags: python, django, weasyprint

In my Django app, I'm using WeasyPrint to convert html report to pdf. I need to send the converted file back to client so they can download it. But I don't see any code on WeasyPrint site where we can get the path of saved file or know in any way where the file was saved.

If I hard code the path, like, `D:/Python/Workspace/report.pdf` and try to open it via javascript, it simply says that the address was not understood.

What is a better way to apporach this issue?

My code:

```
 HTML(string=htmlContent).write_pdf(fileName,
        stylesheets=[CSS(filename='css/bootstrap.min.css')])
```

This is all the code related to WeasyPrint that generated PDF file.

Comment: What about reading the doc ? there's a quite obvious link on the project's homepage... Oh and what about posting your code too ? Are we supposed to guess how you're doing the call ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't even bothered to post the relevant code, but anyway:

If you're using the Python API, you either specify the output file path when calling `weasyprint.HTML().write_pdf()` or get the PDF back as bytestring, [as documented here](http://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#weasyprint.HTML.write_pdf) - and then you can either manually save it to a file somewhere you can redirect your user to or just pass the bytestring to django's `HttpResponse`.

If you're using the commandline (which would be quite surprising from a Django app...), you have to specify the output path too...

IOW : I don't really understand your problem. FWIW, the whole documentation is here : http://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ - and there's a quite obvious link on the project's homepage (which is how I found it FWIW).

*EDIT* : now you posted your actual code: the answer is written in plain in the [FineManual(tm)](http://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#weasyprint.HTML.write_pdf):

> Parameters:    target – A filename, file-like object, or None
>   Returns:
>   The PDF as byte string if target is not provided or None, otherwise None
>   (the PDF is written to target.)

IOW, either you choose to pass the filename for the generated to be generated and serve this file to the user, or you can just pass your Django `HttpResponse` as target, cf [this example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/outputting-pdf/) in Django's doc.

Comment: Check the edited answer - but for spelling out loud: all this is clearly documented in weasyprint's doc, which I posted the link for (despite this link being quite visible on the project's page).